# SubnetIds in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

In a CloudFormation stack, I am creating an Interface type VPC Endpoint, and that requires SubnetIds as one of the parameters. I want to configure the VPC Endpoint in the same CloudFormation stack where I am provisioning the VPC and subnets.

The question is - How do I refer SubnetIds for Subnets created in the same stack? The intrinsic function GetAtt for Subnet does not support retrieving the subnet ids.

Comment: You can import the existing resources to CF. See [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/).

Answer (score 1):

> requires SubnetIds as one of the parameters.

If you provide subnets ids as part of the **parameters to your template**, you can use parameter with `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` type:

```
Parameters:

  Subnets:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

Then in the rest of the code, could refer to entire list or individual subnets as follows:

```
!Ref Subnets # entire list 

!Select [0, !Ref Subnets] # first subnet provided in the list
```

If you create **subnets in your template**:

```
Resources: 
   
   MySubnet1:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
     Properties:
       # properties 

   MySubnet2:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
     Properties:
       # properties other subnet
```

Then to refer to their ids, you can use Ref which [returns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet.html#aws-resource-ec2-subnet-return-values) subnet id:

```
!Ref MySubnet1

!Ref MySubnet2
```

However, if you want to use existing subnets, defined outside of CloudFormation, in your templates, you can **import existing subnets** into your stack:

- [Importing existing resources into a stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html)

But this is not automatic process. You have to manually modify your template first for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Ref` intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) on your Subnet resource such as the example below.

As well as attributes each CloudFormation resource also can support a `Ref` value, for the subnet this is the subnet id.

```
Resources: 
  mySubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: myVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      AvailabilityZone: "us-east-1a"
  Ec2Instance: 
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        Ref: mySubnet
```

Simply use the `Ref` function within the template on the additional resources, this will also create a dependency relationship preventing resources from being created if they rely on the subnet.